# trying to add an additonal product group of "+P"

Tags: sql

just picking up work from an ex-employee and am quite new to SQL, I seem to be picking it up quite quickly but as most of our systems are live, I'm hesitant to make any drastic changes in case the websites based on these systems completely fall over.

The question I have is, there is currently the following code in place:

```
SELECT  *
FROM
(
SELECT  p.product,
        p.description,
        p.warehouse,
        CASE
            WHEN RIGHT(RTRIM(p.product),2) = '+P' THEN (SELECT physical_qty - allocated_qty FROM scheme.stockm p2 WHERE p2.warehouse = p.warehouse AND p2.product = REPLACE(p.product, '+P', ''))
            WHEN RIGHT(RTRIM(p.product),2) = '+P1' THEN (SELECT physical_qty - allocated_qty FROM scheme.stockm p2 WHERE p2.warehouse = p.warehouse AND p2.product = REPLACE(p.product, '+P1', ''))
            ELSE physical_qty - allocated_qty
        END AS 'Stock',
        CASE
            WHEN warehouse = 'X1' THEN trade.price * 0.85
            ELSE trade.price * 0.8
        END AS 'Price'
FROM    scheme.stockm p INNER JOIN
        scheme.oplistm AS trade WITH(NOLOCK) ON p.product = trade.product_code AND trade.price_list = 'MT'
WHERE   (warehouse = 'X1'
OR      warehouse = 'X2')
AND     analysis_b <> '0421'
AND     analysis_b <> '0531'
AND     analysis_b <> '0409'
) AS t
WHERE t.Stock > 0
AND RTRIM(product) + '+P' NOT IN
(SELECT product
FROM    scheme.stockm
WHERE   warehouse = 'X1'
OR      warehouse = 'X2')
AND RTRIM(product) + '+P1' NOT IN
(SELECT product
FROM    scheme.stockm
WHERE   warehouse = 'X1'
OR      warehouse = 'X2')
AND     product NOT LIKE 'BAG%'
AND     product NOT LIKE 'MDS%'
AND     UPPER(description) NOT LIKE '%STAND%'
```

This code pulls through the price lists for all products currently, except for our product range with +p included in the title? I'm enquiring what needs to be done to the current code to include the product range with +p? as this needs to be included.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards
Dean Gent

Comment: Remove `AND RTRIM(product) + '+P' NOT IN
(SELECT product
FROM    scheme.stockm
WHERE   warehouse = 'X1'
OR      warehouse = 'X2')`

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Relational Database - Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: thanks for your response Mihai but that hasn't fixed my issue, just to be a little clearer, im trying to feed through the price for the +P models only, so any product with +p with the same product name should supersede the model without +p. if it doesn't have +p then it will simply display the normal price of the product.